# How to access Windows guest server IP address from Ubuntu Host OS in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am using a Ubuntu 10.04 OS as host and Windows 7 as a guest OS. I want to run some [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) test on my Ubuntu Linux OS whose Selinum server is launched on my Windows 7 guest OS. On the guest OS I can access the Selenium server as `http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub`. However, I am not able to access the same from my host OS.

[image]

I tried a different solution described online, but this combination seemed rare, and I never shortlisted on any answer. Most of the things I've seen were to use the IP address as 10.0.2.2 from the host, which left me trying `http://10.0.2.2:4444/wd/hub` from the host OS with hardly any luck.

Comment: The solution given at [this][1] askubuntu forum solved my problem! 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149218/virtualbox-how-do-i-ping-a-windows-guest-from-the-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Virtual OS's IP address. For Windows 7 as the guest, click on **Start**, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Type `IPCONFIG` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Look for the `IPv4 Address`, and use that in place of the IP address.

The issue is that each device (physical or virtual) requires its own IP address on the network in order to connect. In the default mode, VirtualBox will assign its own address and address range to the virtual machines, and "bridge" the connections with the host to get Internet Access. That is where the whole `10.0.2.2` thing comes in. Your address may be different though, so that's why it's good to just double check as described above.

Comment: I found 10.0.2.15, even that did not work

Comment: Did you check the firewall on the guest?

Comment: I have uploaded the settings as a screenshot. Please take a look

Comment: I disabled the firewall too as you advised. I am using the NAT mode as opposed the Bridge mode

Comment: From Ubuntu's terminal, can you ping `10.0.2.15`?

Comment: oops. i found out i was running a duplicate server in my host OS as well hence i thought things worked. apparently i am still stuck :(

Comment: no, i am not able to 10.0.2.15 from my host

Answer (score 0):

The error you have right now, is that the Guest is able to talk up to the Host, but is registering the wrong ip address for the callback. By using localhost / 127.0.0.1, you can tell Selenium node and grid instances to rely on local port forwarding.

Configure the Guest VM to use NAT Networking, and add a Port Forwarding for port 5555, and port 4444, leaving both ip addresses blank or set to 0.0.0.0 You may also want to forward port 80, so that your Host can see the Guest web server. When using NAT, in the Guest machine, the ip address 10.0.2.2 is the ip address to talk to the Host machine. Here are the commands:

**Host Machine, as Hub**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role hub -port 4444
```

**Guest Machine, as Node**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -host 127.0.0.1 -port 5555 -hub http://10.0.2.2:4444/grid/register
```

For the modern.ie Windows virtual machines, be sure to configure the security settings, particularly for Internet Explorer. A guide can be found here:

http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/